# Linux rw mount option results in ro filesystem

Tags: linux, mount, usb-storage

When I try to mount my external USB HDD under Debian Linux (v9.9, kernel4.9.0-9) I end up with an immutable read-only mount. The whole thing seems counter intuitive, I specify to mount the device as rw and I get ro mount withot any error message to the stdout.

Can someone please advise, where to look for answers?

Command:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,gid=$GID,uid=$UID /dev/sdc1 /mnt/portable
```

Output

```
mount | grep sdc                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
/dev/sdc1 on /mnt/portable type ntfs (ro,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1)
```